# Где вызывать void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) и Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view

Подскажите где вызывать эти методы у наследника View ? при повороте дисплея они не вызываются.

Comment: Не вызывался из-за отсутствия id у элемента view.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [этому источнику](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327348/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestateparcelable-state-are-not-calle) и моему вчерашнему опыту, чтобы эти методы вызывались, необходимо, чтобы ваш наследник View имел id. У меня были такие же проблемы, после чего я добавил id в xml:

```
android:id="@+id/box_drawing_view"
```

и эта проблема была решена/